# Need to run the validation one after check another on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have written email validation Rails ActiveRecord It works fine here is my code for email validation

```
def email_validation

validates :email,
            :presence
validates_format_of :email,
                    with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i,
                    message: 'Invalid email address'
validates_uniqueness_of :email,
                        case_sensitive: false,
                        message: 'Email has already been entered'
end
```

The problem is when I enter the empty email address, I have received the following response message.

```
{
  "status": "E1000",
  "description": {
    "email": [
      "can't be blank",
      "Invalid email address"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here the response message says "can't be blank" and "Invalid Email Adress". What I need is.. I need to validate the first condition and if it success then only I validate the second one. If it is the success then I validate the third one.

I have tried with

```
if email.presence? 
     #condition 1
else 
    #condition 2
    #condition 3
end
```

but it does not work. How do I perform this in sequence check manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Proc here:

```
validates :email, :presence
validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, message: 'Invalid email address', :if => Proc.new { |o| o.errors.empty? }
validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: false, message: 'Email has already been entered', :if => Proc.new { |o| o.errors.empty? }
```